# getOn in Join in Criteria Builder is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I want to join two tables and remove the on clause in join query to set a new custom on clause, however I always get a null predicate from "joinb" so a cant concatenate with more conditions.
My code below.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<myClass> query = cb.createQuery(myClass.class);

Root<a> a = query.from(a.class);
Join<a, b> joinb = a.join("b", JoinType.INNER);
Predicate joinBOn = b.getOn();
b.on(cb.or(joinBOn, cb.or("condition1", "condition2")));
```

The problem here is joinBOn is always null.
I'm new so I don't know what is happening.

Comment: a and b are enitties

Comment: I'm using Criteria Query API to generate dynamic a query.

Answer (score 0):

As documented, [getOn()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Join.html#getOn--)

> Return the predicate that corresponds to the ON restriction(s) on the
>   join, or null if no ON condition has been specified.

In this case there is clearly no ON condition specified, so `null` is expected. That is not an issue, because fetching current ON restriction is not necessary:

```
Predicate condition1 = ...
Predicate condition2 = ...
b.on(cb.or(condition1, condition2));
```